# How to map empty Vaadin TextField to null value in model property

Tags: java, null, vaadin, textfield, android-binder

Default behavior of Vaadin v24 is to map empty TextField to an empty String as model value. How to map it to null value for all TextFields without adding withNullRepresentation to every textField binding?

I've made my own CustomBinder and I'm wondering is this the right way to go. This is the code:

```
public class CustomBinder<BEAN> extends Binder<BEAN> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3555096816850091643L;

    public CustomBinder() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomBinder(Class<BEAN> p_beanType, boolean p_scanNestedDefinitions) {
        super(p_beanType, p_scanNestedDefinitions);
    }

    public CustomBinder(PropertySet<BEAN> p_propertySet) {
        super(p_propertySet);
    }

    public CustomBinder(Class<BEAN> p_class) {
        super(p_class);
    }

    @Override
    public <FIELDVALUE> BindingBuilder<BEAN, FIELDVALUE> forField(HasValue<?, FIELDVALUE> p_field) {
        BindingBuilder<BEAN, FIELDVALUE> forFieldBinding = super.forField(p_field);
        if (p_field instanceof TextField || p_field instanceof TextArea) {
            forFieldBinding = forFieldBinding.withNullRepresentation((FIELDVALUE) "");
        }
        return forFieldBinding;
    }
}
```

Comment: Letting the binder do it, is the more common way.

Comment: I'm letting the binder do it but as default behaviour. I want to avoid putting this "withNullRepresentation" on every text field in my application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.